# Winforms DataGridView custom edit control/cell

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom editing control for my DataGridView in my winforms application, and I'd like to raise an event when the user hits the enter key, but before the datagridview scrolls to the next row. I don't really care if the event is raised by the cell, or the editing control as I can propagate the event as needed.  So far I've tried to override both the OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp methods of the DataGridViewTextBoxCell class which I'm inheriting from and neither of these methods seems to be called if the cell is in editing mode.  I also tried Handling the KeyDown event of the TextBox control in my editing control. This one does get called, but it happens only after the DataGridView has already scrolled to the next row (I need to raise the event before the scroll).  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are creating a custom `DataGridView` control then you can override `ProcessCmdKey` event in `DataGridView` class.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
    int ColumnIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int RowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    if (keyData == Keys.Return || keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {                                
        if (ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0];
        }
        else
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[RowIndex];

        return true;
    }
    else
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did run into this method in my search, I was hoping not to need to custom DataGridView too. This is probably a better solution than my current work around, conditionally raising my event in the CellEndEdit event. Can you think of another way without creating a custom DataGridView? I'm trying to implement this in multiple applications, and I'd prefer not to have to change all of the references in the forms. I'm starting to think that this is not possible though.

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible to handle cell navigation outside the datagridview class. even i have tried to create `KeyDown` event of `EditingControl` when `EditingControlShowing` fired. But, the `KeyDown` event doesn't get response on only `Enter` key press. The event get suppressed when you press enter key. After doing lot of tries finally i have decided to change reference from designer class of my all windows form.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That's exactly what I was experiencing. I'd up vote your answer, but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: Don't worry i don't need it. it is glad that my answer helped you. :)