# Disable Tab key on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to disable tab key from datagridview, also to create my own event on it. Also if it is possible to disable up,down,right,left and enter key.
OnLoad Event

```
this.dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

On KeyDownEvent

```
 private void gridInvoice_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            //SelectNextControl(dataGridView1, true, true, true, true);
            // or Parent.SelectNextControl() if the grid is an only child, etc.
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

With code above tab key it works. I moves to next cell. How can i prevent this?

Comment: Since you have `DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter`, the key events are handled by the DGV Editing Controls: the DGV won't raise the KeyDown/PreviewKeyDown events. You could implement your own Editing Control. See [IDataGridViewEditingControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol). But much depends on what behaviours you want to override and when these overrides should be active.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PreviewKeyDown event instead of KeyDown.

According to [Microsoft Control.PreviewKeyDown Event Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Some key presses, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys, are typically ignored by some controls because they are not considered input key presses.

You need to insert the code below in PreviewKeyDown event if you want to use KeyDown event when Tab is pressed.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) { e.IsInputKey = true; }
```

### When in editmode thanks to Jimi

I'm sorry I thought the problem too simple. How about this. You can override ProcessCmdKey to ignore Tab when you in editmode of your DGV. Is it too brute?
I think this is simple than make a new edit control but not elegance too.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab && dataGridView1.EditingControl != null) { return true; }
        else return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

from [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699521/winforms-datagridview-custom-edit-control-cell)

Comment: Subscribing to the `PreviewKeyDown` might be a good idea. But, the `PreviewKeyDown` event of which Control? If you are in edit mode, can a DataGridView raise that event?